# In DRY Python code, when should I catch/raise exceptions?

Tags: python, error-handling

Given python's principle of duck-typing, when is it best to raise exceptions?

In a simplified case below, say I want to code a couple functions to return booleans based on an input object `product`. Rather than catching an exception if an unexpected object was entered, I'm splitting functionality to keep things DRY.

However, should I also be catching the raised exception in functions that call the abstracted code?

For the options below, which would be the better approach? Are there better approaches still?

**Option 1**

```
TAX_RATE = 0.2

def calculate_price_after_tax(product):
    """Returns Decimal"""
    try:
        net_price = product.price
    except AttributeError:
        raise TypeError('Expected an input of type Product, but received: {0}.'.format(type(product))
    return net_price * TAX_RATE

def is_price_above_100(product):
    """Returns bool"""
    return calculate_price_after_tax(product) > 100

def is_price_above_200(product):
    """Returns bool"""
    return calculate_price_after_tax(product) > 200
```

**Option 2**

```
TAX_RATE = 0.2

def calculate_price_after_tax(product):
    """Returns Decimal"""
    try:
        net_price = product.price
    except AttributeError:
        raise TypeError('Expected an input of type Product, but received: {0}.'.format(type(product))
    return net_price * TAX_RATE

def is_price_above_100(product):
    """Returns bool"""
    try:
        calculate_price_after_tax(product) > 100
    except TypeError as e:
        raise TypeError(e)

def is_price_above_200(product):
    """Returns bool"""
    try:
        calculate_price_after_tax(product) > 200
    except TypeError as e:
        raise TypeError(e)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Option 1 and Option 2 are almmost exactly the same (except that Option 2 is more confusing)

This is because if you don't catch an exception, it will just rise to the top, where it will halt your program. Catching and immediately re-raising it is (almost) the same as never catching it at all.

The only difference can be seen here:

```
In [1]: def f(a, b):
   ...:     return a / b
   ...: 

In [2]: def g(a, b):
   ...:     try:
   ...:         return f(a, b)
   ...:     except ZeroDivisionError as e:
   ...:         raise ZeroDivisionError(e)
```

When calling `g(2, 0)`, the traceback shows us the place where the error was last raised, which is in the function `g`:

```
In [3]: g(2, 0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-9920cf4d7d78> in <module>()
----> 1 g(2, 0)

<ipython-input-2-a48ddeb59e34> in g(a, b)
      3         return f(a, b)
      4     except ZeroDivisionError as e:
----> 5         raise ZeroDivisionError(e)
      6 

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

When defining a third function `h`, that does not re-raise the exception, this does not happen and we see the full context of calling `f` from within `h`:

```
In [4]: def h(a, b):
   ...:     return f(a, b)
   ...: 

In [5]: h(2, 0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-b455367d475f> in <module>()
----> 1 h(2, 0)

<ipython-input-4-7bfa64a165c7> in h(a, b)
      1 def h(a, b):
----> 2     return f(a, b)

<ipython-input-1-44ecddb27ac3> in f(a, b)
      1 def f(a, b):
----> 2     return a / b

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Finally note that if you use just a `raise` (without the explicit exception type and passing it the exception), it will also behave like the function `h`:

```
In [6]: def k(a, b):
   ...:     try:
   ...:         return f(a,b)
   ...:     except ZeroDivisionError:
   ...:         raise
   ...:     

In [7]: k(2, 0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-545f9b93e361> in <module>()
----> 1 k(2, 0)

<ipython-input-6-5891fde4d79f> in k(a, b)
      1 def k(a, b):
      2     try:
----> 3         return f(a,b)
      4     except ZeroDivisionError:
      5         raise

<ipython-input-1-44ecddb27ac3> in f(a, b)
      1 def f(a, b):
----> 2     return a / b

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

So re-raising the exception in this way just obfuscates where the exception originally occurred. This can be a good or a bad thing, but I would not recommend using it unless that is your intention.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to trade a built-in exception for a custom exception:

```
class Product(object):
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.price = price

class InvalidProductError(Exception):
    pass

TAX_RATE = 0.2

def calculate_price_after_tax(product):
    if not hasattr(product, 'price'):
        raise InvalidProductError("product is missing expected attribute price")
    net_price = (1.0 + TAX_RATE) * product.price
    return net_price

def is_price_above_100(product):
    return calculate_price_after_tax(product) > 100

def is_price_above_200(product):
    return calculate_price_after_tax(product) > 200

def main():
    product_list = [Product(50), Product(100), 200]
    for product in product_list:
        try:
            if is_price_above_200(product):
                print("Price is above 200")
            elif is_price_above_100(product):
                print("Price is above 100")
            else:
                print("Price is 100 or below")
        except InvalidProductError:
            print("InvalidProductError: Handle error or skip product")

main()
```

**Output**

```
Price is 100 or below
Price is above 100
InvalidProductError: Handle error or skip product
```

You can filter the custom exception so that you can handle the error or skip the invalid product.

Try it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/KFWY/1)